# What is this pattern/tile board game?

Tags: identify-this-game

It has blocks in different arrangements- L shaped joined, three-in-a-line joined, single. Colours were red, blue and black. The objective of the game as I remember it was to put the tiles/ blocks together in different ways to make a pattern shown in a book that comes in the set, the over-all pattern usually contained in a square outline. Levels range from easy to hard, definitely a game that adults can attempt too. Someone said Tetris but it's nothing like that, although the blocks are similarly structured. Got this as a present when I was younger but I can't for the life of me remember what it's called.

edit: Comments below say it's a variation of Tangram and pentominoes and I think that sounds about right! Hopefully this image will help identify the name. [image: tiles such as these are used to make patterns, you gotta arrange different shapes to form the pattern in the template]

Comment: This sounds like a Tangram, but you describe shapes that are not in the basic one. Maybe a variant of it?

Answer (score 3):

It very much reminds me of a pentomino puzzle. Square board where you try to build certain shapes. I believe Tangram is a pentomino puzzle variant. Linked is an example of what I'm talking about (pieces are made of wood but you get the idea).

[https://www.amazon.com/Square-Root-00012-Pentominoes/dp/B00000IZUL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00000IZUL)

Good luck finding your game!

Answer (score 3):

It looks similar to the
[Kaleidoscope Classic](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Brain-Ed-Limited-BRA001-Kaleidoscope-Classic/dp/B000VS0H9A) board game. One side is red and black, the other side is yellow, blue and black.

[image]